# Displaying multiple images in a view laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to display multiple images which works fine in Laravel 7. I have a product and images where a product has many images. I am able to view all images of a single product using a url like this http://localhost:8000/products/5. This only displays all the images of id 5. Now I want to display all the images from the database for all products in a view but grouped by the name of the product. i.e all the images let's of id 1,2,3.. be displayed in a view. This is the code in my controller. How can I adjust this?

```
  public function getImageData($id)
    {
      $product=Products::find($id);
      $images=$product->images()->get();
     return view('products',['product'=>$product
      ,'images'=>$images

 ]);
           
}
```

and in web.php

```
Route::get('/products/{id}', 'ProductsController@getImageData');
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to get all the images from the database but sorted by product?

Comment: @Zeppo Yes That is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is create a new function that fetches all images for all products, and then put the images on the index of each product. This could implemented in the following way:

```
public function getProductImages(){
    // Fetch all the products 
    $products = Products::all();

    // Create an array to hold the data
    $arrayOfImages = [];

    // Make a foreach over the products to fetch the data
    foreach($products as $product){
        $arrayOfImages[$product->id] = $product->images()->get();
    }

    return view('products', ['productImages' => $product]);
]);
```

After this, you can simply foreach over the specific index to get the images of each product. Forexample

```
foreach($productImages[0] as $productImages){
    // Do the magic here
}
```

Comment: thanks at least i can see some data when I dd() but am having a problem with my front end. Kindly assist I get an error Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). This is the code   <div class="carousel-inner">
 @foreach($productImages[0]  as $image )
    <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="/images2/{{$image->filename}}"/>
    </div>
@endforeach
  </div>

Comment: @user3736334 So, you actually need to do nested foorloops. The first loop will have to target the item, and the inner door-loop will have to target the images. By doing so, you will be able to print them :) There might be some difficulties parsing the data, but I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Zeppo, you can also recommend a tutorial that may guide me if you know any